# how to convert income from one currency into another using a histroical fx table in python with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, one is a income df and the other is a fx df. my income df shows income from different accounts on different dates but it also shows extra income in a different currency. my fx df shows the fx rates for certain currency pairs on the same date the extra income came into the accounts.

I want to convert the currency of the extra income into the same currency as the account so for example, account HP on 23/3 has extra income = 35 GBP, i want to convert that into EUR as that's the currency of the account. Please note it has to use the fx table as i have a long history of data points to fill and other accounts so i do not want to manually code 35 * the fx rate. Finally i then want to create another column for income df that will sum the daily income + extra income in the same currency together

im not sure how to bring both df together so i can get the correct fx rate for that sepecifc date to convert the currency of the extra income into the currency of the account

my code is below

```
import pandas as pd

income_data = {'date': ['23/3/22', '23/3/22', '24/3/22', '25/3/22'], 'account': ['HP', 'HP', 'JJ', 'JJ'],
        'daily_income': [1000, 1000, 2000, 2000], 'ccy of account': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'USD', 'USD'],
        'extra_income': [50, 35, 10, 12.5], 'ccy of extra_income': ['EUR', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'USD']}

income_df = pd.DataFrame(income_data)

fx_data = {'date': ['23/3/22', '23/3/22', '24/3/22', '25/3/22'], 'EUR/GBP': [0.833522, 0.833522, 0.833621, 0.833066],
        'USD/EUR': [0.90874, 0.90874, 0.91006, 0.90991]}

fx_df = pd.DataFrame(fx_data)
```

the final df should look like this (i flipped the fx rate so 1/0.833522 to get some of the values)

[image]

Would really appreicate if someone could help me with this. my inital thpought was merge but i dont have a common column and not sure if map function would work either as i dont have a dictionary. apologies in advance if any of my code is not greate - i am still self learning, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a common column for merging in both data frames. Below uses `assign` to add columns and `Series` operators (over arithmetic ones: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`).

```py
# ADD NEW COLUMN AS CONCAT OF CCY COLUMNS
income_data = income_data.assign(
    currency_ratio = lambda df: df["ccy of account"] + "/" + df["ccy of extra_income"]
)

# ADD REVERSED CURRENCY RATIOS
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG FORMAT
fx_data_long = pd.melt(
    fx_data.assign(**{
        "GBP/EUR": lambda df: df["EUR/GBP"].div(-1),
        "EUR/USD": lambda df: df["USD/EUR"].div(-1)
    }),
    id_vars = "date",
    var_name = "currency_ratio",
    value_name = "fx_rate"
)

# MERGE AND CALCULATE
income_data = (
    income_data.merge(
        fx_data_long,
        on = ["date", "currency_ratio"],
        how = "left"
    ).assign(
        total_income = lambda df: df["daily_income"].add(df["extra_income"].mul(df["fx_rate"]))
    )
)
```